# How to use a Macro in one workbook to read and analyze data in multiple others- Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked at a bunch of articles to try to figure this out, but nothing seems to be working. I have built a macro in an Excel workbook to practice collecting the data and making the tables I want, and now I want to apply it to many other workbooks in a different folder, not the original one I was using for practice. I kept it in the same location but wrote lines I thought would apply it to other locations. Oddly, the code I have will make changes to the new file, but all of the changes are from reading the data in the workbook I have been practicing with. For example, it will add sheets to the new file, but it fills each workbook with the same information instead of the information from the book it is changing.

Here is what I have:

```
Sub LoopFiles()
Dim MyFileName, FilenameNew, MyPath As String
Dim MyBook As Workbook

MyPath = "C:\ExcelT2\"
MyFileName = Dir(MyPath & "*.csv")

Do Until MyFileName = ""
    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFileName)
    Set MyBook = ActiveWorkbook

    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)

With wb1

wb1.Worksheets(1).Select
.
.
.
```

After this it just reads data from the first sheet line by line, but it isn't reading from the first sheet of the workbook I opened. I don't know what is going wrong. Here is just a sample line from one place where I read in data:

```
ra1 = Cells(i, 7)
.
.
.
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(prevval, 3) = ra1
```

This pulls data from the wrong workbook but puts it in the right sheet in the newly opened workbook. Please help!

***Update

This line gives me an application or object defined error now..

```
ElseIf wb1.Worksheets(1).Cells(i, 3) <> wb1.Worksheets(1).Cells((i - 1), 3) Then
```

Comment: Try qualifying this `After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` by including a workbook object. Something like: `After:=wb1.Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)` and try not to use `ActiveWorkbook` as it can yield unpredictable results.

Comment: Work with the object you've created, like: `With wb1.Sheets("Sheet1")` `ra1 = .Cells(i, 7)` `End With` and `With wb1.Sheets("Sheet2")` `.Cells(prevval, 3) = ra1` `End With`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the changes below I made. These changes are made to explicitly qualify all the objects you are working with. Otherwise, there are default behaviors in the way VBA reads the lines that will throw the code in a different direction (like referring to the unintended workbook or worksheet.

```
Do Until MyFileName = ""

Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFileName)
'Set MyBook = ActiveWorkbook --> wb1 is already set to newly opened file

With wb1 '--> work directly with wb1

    .Sheets.Add After:= .Worksheets(.Worksheets.Count) '--> add the "." in front of object to qualify it to parent (wb1 in this case)

     '..... 

     ra1 = .Workhseets(1).Cells(i,7)

     .Worksheets(2).Cells(prevval, 3) = ra1

    '....

End With
```

Comment: For some reason now I am getting Error 1004 (application-defined or object defined error) on a line where I am comparing two cells. Added an edit to op with problem line.

Comment: if your original question was answered and you have a new question, please create a new question and mark this as answered. If your original was not answered, please tell me (us) what is not working with the original question as asked.

Comment: That is what I did. Your fix did not fix the problem, rather it made my code stop running. Whether or not this is a new problem or the same one, I'm not sure, but regardless I added an update to the original question for clarification on what is going on. I still think it has to do with specifying the location of the changes, but the update line is what it doesn't like.

Comment: @Rosie - Fair point. In looking at your edited question, the line itself looks good. However, in the context of how it works in your code it is hard to tell since you only show snippets that don't really go together. If you post a more full code block the error may become clearer to us.

Comment: I think I found my problem, which was a small unrelated typo. your answer helped get it on the right track, I followed what you said and I think it works. Thanks!